# Qt's QTest doesn't select an item in a drop-down list with a click

Tags: qt, qcombobox, mouseclick-event, qlistview, qtest

There are two drop-downs. I'm trying to click on an item in a drop-down from a QComboBox.

For this purpose I created a function, launched for both drop-downs, here's an excerpt:

```
constexpr int DELAY{ 1000 };

void clickDropDown(int row, QComboBox *comboBox)
    {
    QListView *dropDownList = comboBox->findChild<QListView *>();    
    QModelIndex foundIndex{ dropDownList->model()->index(row, 0) };

    QRect foundDropDownItem = dropDownList->visualRect(foundIndex);
    QPoint foundDropDownItemPosition = foundDropDownItem.center();

    QWidget *activeWidget = dropDownList->viewport();   
    QTest::mouseClick(activeWidget, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier, foundDropDownItemPosition);
    QTest::qWait(DELAY); // waits 1 second
}
```

Now the flow looks like this:

- First drop-down list is shown,
- The item is highlighted (mouseClick) as chosen, but not really *selected*, not *chosen*
- UI test goes to the second column, the first column shows the first element in the list (i.e., the upper-most), despite what was highlighted;
- An item in the second drop-down is *selected*/*chosen*

So, the second list seems to be working with this function, the first one doesn't. I need these items to be selected, not just highlighted.

I run on **Ubuntu 21.04**. Seems to work well on **Windows 10**. Seems to fail on Mac. Any suggestions how to make it work?

**What works:**
`two clicks` + `Enter`, but this will crash on MacOs. So that's not really a solution.
Also, it destroys the `dropDownList` object, and if make with an interval, will lead to a crash.

**What else doesn't work:** `key down` N times.

**Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.

That's Qt's bug (as of Fall 2021), described here:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-77772. The mouse clicked not the button, but some point nearby. Why it was selected and why it failed to react otherwise is still a mystery.

**Decision:** I left this test to run on Windows and Linux only, closing it for Mac.